# How does the income of your target audience matter for logo design?

Tags: logo, branding

I see this question being asked in logo and branding discovery phases. Anyone want to weigh in as to why this is?

Comment: Graphic design IS marketing. To think any differently, you’re just doodling

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fast moving consumer goods (FMCG) are sold to consumers, and one of the fundamental principles of marketing is the market segmentation. Companies offer various products for the various segments based on their income level. So in order to target a certain audience, you need to know the average income.

A premium-looking product will appeal to a different audience than a cheap one, and the branding is part of that experience.

Comment: @Tetsujin Except it really isnt comparable. Android versus iPhone are really different products. But in grocery goods its perfectly possible that the exact same product (sic) is sold at different prices. So its more like a iphone vs iphone (in brown bag) comparasion.

Comment: @joojaa - No-one has yet mentioned what the product is, however, the 2nd paragraph of the answer perfectly fits the iPhone/Android scenario. Demographics even use it as an income indicator.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes but logo has much more relative value in a box of cereal than in iPhone/Android where features are different. But in the cereal it may in some cases be ONLY the branding. So it is a queation of x% vs 100%. And no i dont think iphone vs android is even close to the same.

Comment: There are more expensive (and elegant) Android Phones than Iphones. The comparation has no sense. Android is only the operating system, not the full product.

Comment: Given an equivalent iPhone and and Android phone, the iPhone is probably more expensive - so it's perfectly comparable.

Comment: @Tetsujin iPhone vs Android is more elegant vs technological. Neither is more high end (technological and wealthy are just as connected as elegant and wealthy), but the logos do sort of show a difference in design and market. The iPhone is for someone who wants something simple and just works. It hides all the complicated details. The Android device is for someone who wants more control and capability, sometimes at the cost of simplicity and elegance. I think the logos somewhat reflect this.

Comment: Why does this answer focus on "fast moving consumer goods"? The question makes no mention of goods or product. The organization in question may be a company that provides a service or it may be a non-commercial organization.

Comment: @sean Because logosand branding have most relative value in that segment. Its also the segment where the income segmentation is largest, then come cars and then consumer electronics.

Answer (score 18):

People which frequent "Horror" movies are generally not the same people which attend the "Emotional Drama". Both equally viable audiences, but vastly different in terms of what appeals to them.

The same general division can be found in financial capabilities. A family bordering on the poverty line are not the people purchasing luxury items. And luxury item purchasers are not the individuals shopping at the local dollar store.

Just as branding for Men varies from the branding for Women, so should the branding based upon financial capabilities vary.

- Luxury brands often have a specific air about them, script type, lots of white space, ambiguous symbols, muted or pastel limited colors.
- Lower-end brands typically use "louder" color, more color, bolder type, identifiable symbology or even mascots/comic type of symbology.

If a brand appears too "luxury" to more price-minded consumers, they may simply overlook the brand entirely based upon a visual snap-judgement. And the converse is also true - a brand which appears to be more "loud" or "bold" may be overlooked by luxury buyers as "not for them."

The brand should "feel" like it belongs to the audience to some degree. Stepping out of that constraint can often alienate the brand with the very audience they are trying to reach. There's a reason all the "Monster Truck Rally" advertising is loud, in-your-face, and uses a rainbow of colors. And there's a reason "perfume" ads you see are esoteric, ambiguous, lofty, monotone, and often a bit pretentious....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90010/discussion-on-answer-by-scott-how-does-the-income-of-your-target-audience-matter).